# Phaser: How to use a simple timer from 0 to 3

Tags: javascript, timer, phaser-framework, game-development

I am using the following code *(which is a simplified snippet in order to make it more readable)*:

```js
var player;
var box_tnt;

function create (){
    this.physics.add.collider(player, box_tnt, hitTnt, null, this);
}

//the function hitTnt stop the game because the player died
function hitTnt (player, boxes){
    this.physics.pause();
    player.setTint(0xff0000);
    player.anims.play('default');
    gameOver = true;
    textGameOver.setText('GAME OVER');
}
```

- **Actual comportment:**

When the player hit the bomb: player die; end of the game

- **Desired comportment:**

When the player hits the bomb: the bomb waits 3 secondes and then explodes ! If the player is too close he dies.
But I struggle a lot to use a timer even after reading a lot of examples in the forum. I am a newbie concerning Phaser so I didn't succeed to it so far.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using Phaser 3, these are the ways you can use timer.

1. delayedCall method, which is shorter.

`delayedCall(delay, callback, args, callbackScope)`

So, you would do something like this.

`this.time.delayedCall(2000, onEvent, null, this);`

2. addEvent method

`addEvent(config)` [Docs for config](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/global.html#TimerEventConfig)

`this.time.addEvent({ delay: 2000, callback: onEvent, callbackScope: this });`

Find these method in the docs [here](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Time.Clock).

Find examples for timer events [here](https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=time/&q=).

---

Other thing you can do is if you've any tween that plays for 3 second (If you're tweening bomb or animating it for 3 seconds). You can attach `onComplete` callback to it. So after Tween gets over that `onComplete` callback would get executed.

Comment: This is the Phaser-recommended approach. I have used both the `delayedCall` and `addEvent` methods and either should provide the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay the executino of `hitTnt()` logic by 3 seconds, you can wrap it in a `setTimeout()` call like that:

```
function hitTnt(player, boxes) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.physics.pause();
        player.setTint(0xff0000);
        player.anims.play('default');
        gameOver = true;
        textGameOver.setText('GAME OVER');
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking how to do it using Phaser syntax but I wasn't aware that I could simply use javascript for that ! It makes things way easier.

Comment: Agree, with setTimeout pausing/resuming the game will mess everythings up